# Как сделать поиск который понимает суть запроса?

Tags: архитектура, поиск, elasticsearch, поисковые-системы

На сайте есть много категорий, например автомобили, запчасти, мобильные телефоны, недвижимость.
Задача сейчас стоит такая: нужно сделать поиск который будет понимать запрос и будет настраивать фильтры для данного запроса. То есть поиск не должен искать ключевые слова в заголовке и описание товара, а должен настраивать фильтры чтоб найти нужный товар.

Приведу несколько примеров:

- **красный айфон в Москве** - система должна понимать что айфон относиться
  к категорий мобильных телефонов, производитель Apple, цвет красный
  тоже должен выбираться в отдельном фильтре, а в Москве относиться к
  фильтру местоположения, соотвественно выбираем страну Россия -
  Московская область
- **bmw e39 в Японий** - выбирается категория
  автомобили, производитель Bmw, модель 5 серия, год производства
  1996-2003, местонахождение страна Япония

таких примеров можно привести еще очень много, но думаю суть задачи ясна
характеристики всех товаров есть в базе данных

сейчас нужно сделать подсказки для поиска, то есть стоит задача преобразовать поисковой запрос в несколько вариантов поиска, один из которых выберет пользователь

но вопрос в том как это технически реализовать? в проекте уже используется elasticsearch, думаю тоже в нем создать индекс где будут все характеристики товаров, места, категорий и туда-же еще добавить какие-то кастомные запросы которые будут создавать администраторы

на сколько ли правильный такой подход? может у кого есть идей или опыт в реализации такой задачи
буду благодарен за любые полезные материалы или советы!

---

UPDATE: добавлю еще что сайт имеет много языков, и исправление ошибок в поисковом запросе рассматривается как отдельная задача, сейчас думаем только над тем как преобразовать запрос в настройки фильтра

Comment: Задача выглядит сложной, мне нечем подсказать, но я бы начал с поиска готовых решений. Такой поиск отличается от обычного тем, что должен "понимать" как связаны термины между собой (типа я пишу, что хочу звонилку от Apple и поиск понимает, что речь про айфоны).

Comment: Если готовых решений нет на это (в чем я сомневаюсь), то задача кратно усложняется, так как [информационный поиск](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA) - это прямо целая наука, тогда можно начинать [отсюда](https://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1623-5.html)